# Change conref during processing by xsl-fo

Tags: xsl-fo, dita

I read somewhere, that conditional importing is not possible in xsl-fo. Although I have small hope, that this is something else, and can be resolved.

My problem is that I have something like that in one of my dita file:

```
<row>
    <entry align="right">Intended Purpose</entry>
    <entry ><p conref="intendedpurpose.dita#intendedpurpose/statement" ></p></entry>
 </row>
```

My question is, can I somehow change the conref in xsl-fo, and add variable to the dita file i want to upload? I mean something like that

```
intendedpurpose{version}.dita
```

I am just curious if it can be somehow done.

Answer (score 1):

You need to transform your DITA XML into the FO vocabulary for your FO processor to be able to use it.

You could pre-process your DITA XML to add the version number in `intendedpurpose.dita` and similar filenames before running your regular DITA processing or you may be able to customise the DITA-to-FO processing to do the conref lookup on the right file, but it's definitely something that you'd do before you have an FO file to feed to the FO processor.

Answer (score 0):

It would be far better to use conkeyref and target a key defined in a topicref. Doing so late-binds the target so that the resolution occurs during processing and not authoring. That changes your paragraph element to

```
<p conkeyref="purpose/intendedpurpose"/>
```

In the map, you would then have a topicref that points to the topic that contains the paragraph target. It would look something like:

```
<topicref keys="purpose" href="intendedpurpose_v3.dita">
```

The topic referenced contains the paragraph with the @id intendedpurpose.